# Webcam Capture/Panel JavaFx and Swing

Tags: swing, javafx, jpanel, javafx-2, webcam

I am using the sarxos webcam capture and I successfully have it working in Swing with a with the Webcam Panel which uses Jpanel.

I now need to use this in my Java Fx application.

So my question is, how do I put a Swing Jpanel in say an anchor pane, or something else?

I looked at Swing Node but couldn't find examples for this?

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: The [API docs for `SwingNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html) have a code sample. You just call `setContent(...)` on the `SwingNode`.

Comment: Unbelievable, can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you very much!